# CSS selector :last-child

Tags: css

Why is the 3rd `a` element not in **lightgreen** color?

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
div.poncho {
    background-color: #555;
    font-size: 200%; 
    padding: 1em;
}
div.poncho a[poncho] {
    color: bisque;
}
div.poncho a:first-child {
    color: darkcyan;
}
div.poncho a:last-child {
    color: lightgreen;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="poncho">
        <a poncho>poncho 1</a>
        <br>
        <a poncho>poncho 2</a>
        <br>
        <a poncho>poncho 3</a>
        <br> <!-- if removed, it works as expected -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `a` is not the last-child, the `<br>` is. You could try `:last-of-type` which has decent browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you can use **[:last-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)** Selector.

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
div.poncho {
    background-color: #555;
    font-size: 200%; 
    padding: 1em;
}
div.poncho a[poncho] {
    color: bisque;
}
div.poncho a:first-child {
    color: darkcyan;
}
div.poncho a:last-of-type {
    color: lightgreen;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="poncho">
        <a poncho>poncho 1</a>
        <br>
        <a poncho>poncho 2</a>
        <br>
        <a poncho>poncho 3</a>
        <br> <!-- if removed, it works as expected -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:last-child` means exactly what it says.

Since your `<a>` has a `<br>` after it, it isn't the **last** child.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `a` in `a:last-child`?

Comment: @Vidul: To filter on the tag name too (in particular, that won't match the `<br>`)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and concrete answer. Still, the CSS selectors' logic makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Vidul: Why not? What don't you understand?

Comment: Each part of the selector (`a`, `:blah`, etc) just further filters which element(s) it can match.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. If `a` does not matter (and it does not), why would one want to specify it at all?!

Comment: It is that simple: `a` should mean `a` heance `a:last-child` should mean the last `a`. That is how I understand it.

Comment: It **does** matter – it prevents it from matching the last element if it isn't `<a>`.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong; that's not how CSS works.  Each simple selector further filters the match, and is not related to the others.

Comment: Also, it is totally possible to make selectors with extra parts – you can even write `.Class.Class`

Comment: "it prevents it from matching the last element if it isn't <a>" - that makes sense already. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the pseudo-selector you should be using is

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

> Using :last-of-type is very similar to :nth-child but with one
>   critical difference: it is less specific. In the example above, if we
>   had used p:nth-last-child(1), nothing would happen because the
>   paragraph is not the last child of its parent (the ). This
>   reveals the power of :last-of-type: it targets a particular type of
>   element in a particular arrangement with relation to similar siblings,
>   not all siblings.